# How to access subcollection in firestore after .where

Tags: javascript, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection and an array of names and the collection can be queried directly by id

I want to access a unique subcollection depending on a name and I want to return the sub collection after

Query is structured as such

```
firestore
.collection
.where("name", '==', inputName)
.collection('subCollection')
.get()
```

This does not seem to work, is there an alternative way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore queries can only inspect data in the documents that they return. There is no way to return documents from the subcollection, and filter on a field from the parent documents.

The common solution is to add the `name` to each document in the subcollections too (say as a field called `parentName`), and then perform a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) across all collections named `subCollection`:

```
firestore
.collectionGroup('subCollection')
.where("parentName", '==', inputName)
.get()
```